# Joomla Admin Side URL Changed from & to &nbsp; in URL String

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, checkin

i had change server of my joomla website
but i got now some issue in administrator panel the URL of Page has been changed from `&` to `&nbsp;`

When i tried to edit any Article its give lock option near the name mins checkin, i dont understand whats that and url will goes like this

```
http://60pluslife.org/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;layout=edit&amp;id=2
```

actually url is that

```
http://60pluslife.org/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit&id=2
```

Give me Suggestions Please

Answer (score 0):

The lock icon saying "Checkin" means that the article is currently edited by the user stated in the tooltip. This is done to prevent multiple users editing the same article at the same time.
Often this is caused when you try to edit an article, and then exit out of the form by using the browsers back key or by closing the window. You should always use either one of the save or cancel buttons.
Clicking on the lock icon will check this article back in and allows to edit again by others.

As for the question about the ampersand (`&amp;` not `&nbsp;` like in question): Joomla itself shouldn't generate this kind of URLs.
Maybe you can give more informations about what version of Joomla (from the URLs you posted it's not Joomla 1.5 you tagged), which type of server (apache, IIS?) and what browser you use (Does it happen on all browsers). Also do you have any non-core extensions installed?